MongoDB find multiple latest by filter criteria
Imagine the following sample data:
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "category": "FIRE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T07:11:00Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "category": "FIRE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T08:11:00Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "category": "FIRE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T09:11:00Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "category": "POLICE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T07:22:00Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "category": "POLICE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T08:22:00Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "category": "POLICE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T09:22:00Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "category": "AMBULANCE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T07:33:00Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "category": "AMBULANCE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T08:33:00Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": 9,
    "category": "AMBULANCE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T09:33:00Z"
  }
]

For each combination in a set of categories (e.g. ["FIRE", "AMBULANCE"]) and timestamps (e.g. ["2024-05-11T08:15:00Z", "2024-05-11T09:00:00Z"]), I'd like to get the latest entry on or before each timestamp for each category:
[
  {
    "category": "FIRE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T08:15:00Z",
    "last_entry_on_or_before": {
      "_id": 2,
      "category": "FIRE",
      "time": "2024-05-11T08:11:00Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "category": "FIRE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T09:00:00Z",
    "last_entry_on_or_before": {
      "_id": 2,
      "category": "FIRE",
      "time": "2024-05-11T08:11:00Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "category": "AMBULANCE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T08:15:00Z",
    "last_entry_on_or_before": {
      "_id": 7,
      "category": "AMBULANCE",
      "time": "2024-05-11T07:33:00Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "category": "AMBULANCE",
    "time": "2024-05-11T09:00:00Z",
    "last_entry_on_or_before": {
      "_id": 8,
      "category": "AMBULANCE",
      "time": "2024-05-11T08:33:00Z"
    }
  }
]

Is this possible to do in a single efficient aggregation pipeline? I have a compound index on [category, time].

You can use $documents to generate the combinations of your arrays with $unwind. Then, simply do a $lookup to find the matching records and chain up $sort and $limit to get the latest record.
db.aggregate([
  {
    "$documents": [
      {
        "category": //your input category array here
        [
          "FIRE",
          "AMBULANCE"
        ],
        //your input time array here
        "time": [
          "2024-05-11T08:15:00Z",
          "2024-05-11T09:00:00Z"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$category"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$time"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "category",
      "foreignField": "category",
      "let": {
        ts: "$time"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $lte: [
                "$time",
                "$$ts"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "time": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "$limit": 1
        }
      ],
      "as": "last_entry_on_or_before"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$last_entry_on_or_before"
  }
])

Mongo Playground
The syntax in playground is slightly different since $documents is not allowed in playground directly and need to work around that. For your actual mongo shell/other driver, the above syntax should work.

first time seeing $documents

Used $documents before but this usage is so nice!
